# Anne McCaffrey's Dragonflight: Originally a Lost Colony prelude?

Tags: pern, anne-mccaffrey

Did Anne McCaffrey's original 1968 *Dragonflight* include the *Lost Colony* prelude?  To the best of my recollection it did, but I don't have the original handy any more, and I've came across online suggestions that the SF portion (lost space colony) was added/edited in later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes, the "lost colony" beginning was in the original magazine publication of "Weyr Search" and carried through in every republication.** Only excerpts of the 1967 Analog with Weyr Search are [online at Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=IuYsAQAAIAAJ&q=%22Rukbat%22&dq=%22Rukbat%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uyodUr-zA8rOsATkpoEI&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBg), but the linked excerpt includes lines clearly from an introduction establishing that this is a fallen colony:

> It was during the frantic struggle to combat this menace dropping
> through Pern’s skies like silver threads that Pern’s contact with the
> mother-planet weakened and broke.

Furthermore, in the comments [Organic Marble](https://Organic%20Marble) provided a link to the [entire October 1967 issue of Analog](https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/luminist/SF/AN/AN_1967_10.pdf) which positively confirms that the original publication of "Weyr Search" included the prologue identifying Pern as a lost colony world.

Comment: The entire October 1967 Analog is available here https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/luminist/SF/AN/AN_1967_10.pdf It has the full prologue.

Comment: Thank you- I'll revise later tonight

Answer (score 5):

The novel *Dragonflight* was a fix-up, made up mostly of material from two earlier novellas:  "Weyr Search" and "Dragonrider," both published in 1967 in *Analog*.  ("Dragonrider" was sufficiently long that it was further split into two parts and published across two issues.)  The novel version came out the next year.

As has always been common with fix-ups, the author added some additional material for the novel publication.  The "prelude" (as you put it) was written as party of this process, with McCaffrey fleshing out the history of the world.

Comment: I am particularly interested in the part of the prelude that implies the story is about a Lost Space Colony, and not a world where the people were always there. Was that element in there from the beginning or added in later?